# How to avoid 'eval' in this react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval, gatsby

I am using Gatsby static page generator to create a static website. I have created a component like this:

```
const Subject = ({data, location, pageContext) => {
    const currentPage = eval("pagecontext.num" + (pageContext.queryfor) + "s")
    return (
        console.log(currentPage) //returns page number as expected
    )
}
```

As you can see, I am using `eval` to construct a variable based on some strings and another variable. The code runs perfectly, as expected but I get a warning:

```
warn ESLintError:
E:\Build\gatsby\src\components\subject.js
warning  eval can be harmful  no-eval
```

Them I read a bit about how eval should never be used as it is dangerous. How can I avoid using `eval` in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to [bracket notation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781):

```js
const Subject = ({data, location, pageContext) => {
    const currentPage = pageContext[`num${pageContext.queryfor}s`])
    return (
        console.log(currentPage) //returns page number as expected
    )
}
```

Comment: Nearly perfect. You added a stray ")". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
let myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("pagecontext.num" + (pageContext.queryfor) + "s", VALUE_OF_THIS_VARIABLE)
...
// then access it like before:
const currentPage = myMap.get("pagecontext.num" + (pageContext.queryfor) + "s")
```